# How to -trim this image using ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick, trim, imagemagick-convert

I understand `-trim` can be used to remove extra whitespace.

How can Imagemagick be used to convert:

**Note:** The size of the bottom border to be removed is not known.

[image]

to

[image]

**Note:** the default `-trim` flag does not work.

The output of `convert -trim pre-trim.png post-trim.png` is:

[image]

which is missing the borders on the left and right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

You can add some strips of colour down one side to protect the other 3 sides, then trim the side you want to trim and then remove the protective strips.

```
magick frame.png -gravity north    \
   -background cyan    -splice x10 \
   -background magenta -splice x10 \
   -rotate 90 -trim +repage        \
   -gravity east -chop 10x -rotate -90 result.png
```

Here is the intermediate image of how it looks with the protective strips prior to trimming:

[image]

Kudos to Anthony Thyssen for his excellent **ImageMagick Usage** pages [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#trim_oneside).

**Original Answer**

You can chop 68 pixels off the bottom with:

```
convert frame.png -gravity south -chop x68 result.png
```

Comment: What if the number of pixels on the bottom is unknown?  The color is known, however.